# What does Eclipse CDT come with?

Tags: c, eclipse

This is what i currently have installed on my home computer:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr2

Now, that was a pain to setup because you needed to use Cygwin to install a bunch of stuff in order for Eclipse to compile and run a C project. I found this the other day:

http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/

Does Eclipse CDT come with everything it needs to compile and run a C program or does it still depend on external files? Does it come with a standard library?

Comment: If you click through the eclipse.org/cdt support pages you get http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14222/C-Development-using-eclipse-IDE-Starters-guide which says *For running CDT from eclipse, you need to have the following tools. Make tools for make process.
GNU compiler collection (GCC) for compilations. GDB for debugging.
You can download all these tools from www.MinGW.org.*

Comment: Of the toolchain choices (MSVC, mingw, cygwin) that you have, cygwin is by far the most painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use **Cygwin** and you can use alternatives such as **mingw** (it is simpler for most people to install).  Checkout this tutorial for detailed description how to setup on Windows:
http://www.banym.de/eclipse/install-eclipse-cdt-on-windows-7

Compiler is responsible for standard library and in the case mentioned above it is mingw.

If you are on other hand interested about MAC OS installation checkout:

- http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Eclipse/CDT_on_Linux_and_Mac_OS_X
- http://max.berger.name/howto/cdt/cdt.jsp